# OleDbConnectionStringBuilder подключение

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Решаю задачу на шарпе (сразу говорю, что знаю базу лишь шарпа).

Как правильно выполнить подключение к access базе через OleDbConnectionStringBuilder с целью внегридного вывода?

Смотрел в сети примеры через SqlConnection, но там не поддерживаются провайдеры для access базы формата mdb. Хотелось бы увидеть кратенький пример, от начала коннекта и описанием строки провайдера, а также процесс цикличного вывода данных из произвольной таблицы. В сети информация фрагментарная.
Спасибо за ответы, всем!

Answer (score 1):

```
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder =
        new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0";
builder.DataSource = @"C:\Sample.mdb";
string savedConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Предупреждаю сразу, работает только с Microsoft Access 2003. Начиная с 2007 версии меняется провайдер. ЕГО НАДО СТАВИТЬ ОТДЕЛЬНО. [ссылка на провайдера](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). Если его не поставить, то не будет работать подключение.
Как только поставите, пишете в коде вместо

```
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0";
```

Пишете

```
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0";
```

Номер версии зависит от базы Access. Уточняйте у гугла.

Comment: Например, sql-запрос select * from Students, где надо циклично вывести данные в массив. Если через Connection просто через метод Open, то в вашем случае как?

Comment: Не подскажете, как дальше со сторокой builder работать? Например, в цикле вывести данные из условной таблицы Student через цикл foreach или while?